# Find the distance travelled by the stone in the last two seconds given the following conditions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A stone, allowed to fall under gravity falls  $5t^2$m in t seconds.Find the distance travelled by the stone in the last two seconds before it reaches the ground,if the stone is dropped from a height of $180$ m.

options:

a)$30$m b)$60$m c)$100$m d)$90$m

MyApproach:

I am not able to think logically how to use the formula to solve the problem.

Given,

@Edit

$1$/$2$ g . $t^2$=$5t^2$

$5t^2$= $180$

=>t=6

To calculate the distance in the last 2 sec I did $5$ . $(6)^2$-$5$ . $(4)^2$=100m

> Is the approach right?

Comment: Which formula are you using?

Comment: @JohnDouma I have done editing.

Comment: You know that $5t^2=180\implies t=6$. Figure out the velocity after 4 seconds and use that to set up the initial velocity for a problem that calculates how far a falling body will fall after 2 seconds.

Comment: @JohnDouma What about a?

Comment: It is a falling body so normally a should be g which is 9.81. However, this problem is set up so that $\frac{1}{2}gt^2=5t^2$ which implies that a = g = 10. Use 10 so that the answer comes out nice and neat like in the choices.

Comment: Your answer is correct.